# Google Geocoding API no results with php-CUrl

Tags: php, curl, geocoding

I have a problem with the Google Geocoding API.
When I go to the URL corresponding to the api call I want
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6+QUAI+DE+LORIENT+94569+RUNGIS+CEDEX&key=[API_KEY]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6+QUAI+DE+LORIENT+94569+RUNGIS+CEDEX&key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D) I have 2 results. When I ask It throught php-CUrl, I have a "No Result" response.
On 300 differents addresses, I have a few like it (15 at most). I don't know why.

I tried a few things :
classic Curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Curl Class (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class):

```
$curl->setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36');
$curl->setHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');
$curl->setHeader('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch');
$curl->setHeader('accept-langage', 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4');
$curl->setHeader('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8');
$curl->setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
$curl->setHeader('authority', 'maps.googleapis.com');
$curl->get($url);
```

With and without user-agent/headers.

Comment: I would suggest adding a country code to your query. I've seen a lot of "mismatches" due to google not knowing which country to look. So: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6+QUAI+DE+LORIENT+94569+RUNGIS+CEDEX,FR&key=[API_KEY]

Comment: The strange thing is, when I proceed the url with Google Chrome, I have 2 results... I'm gonna try with the country code

Comment: When i enter the exact URL in the browser it will give me 0 results as well... with a country code I do get results

Comment: Works fine. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independed from CURL or whatever request method is being used, I would suggest always adding a countrycode at the end of the query string so google knows where to look instead of guessing based on parameters / requestheaders.

Notice the difference between:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6+QUAI+DE+LORIENT+94569+RUNGIS+CEDEX');
var_dump(json_decode($result));

$result = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6+QUAI+DE+LORIENT+94569+RUNGIS+CEDEX,FR');
var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

First one does not give results, the second one does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the cURL code given is that you do not have sufficient options set for the request. You are attempting to retrieve from an https address but your curl request does not acknowledge this.

You need to have a copy of cacert.pem somewhere on your system and refer to that using the cainfo option in curl. You can [download cacert.pem here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

Then you need to refer to this in your curl configuration.

```
    /* I would NOT recommend storing cacert in your document root but this is just as an example. */

    $cacert=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cacert.pem';
    if( !file_exists( realpath( $cacert ) ) exit('cant find certificate bundle');


    $url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=dundee,scotland';

    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
    }
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY, CURLCLOSEPOLICY_OLDEST );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE );

    $payload=array_filter( array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'info'          =>  curl_getinfo( $curl ),
            'errors'        =>  curl_error( $curl )
        ) 
    );
    curl_close( $curl );
    print_r( $payload );
```